# Stop click on body tag when pop up opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a script on jquery ready function when pop up is opened and if I click on body tag it close the pop up. I ant if clicked on body other than pop up part do not close pop up. I have tried many method but does not work. pop up open on ready function rather to click event. So there is no click to open pop up. It open as visitor open the site. and close after success login. so if visitor is not login pop up should no closed.
Html

```
{% form 'customer_login' %}
<header class="page-header">
<h1>Customer Login</h1>
</header>  
{% include 'form-errors-custom' %}
 <label for="customer_email">Email Address<em>*</em></label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="customer_email" 

{% if form.errors contains "email" %} class="error"{% endif %} >  
{% if form.password_needed %}
 <label for="customer_password">Password<em>*</em></label>
<input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="customer_password" {% if form.errors contains "password" %} class="error"{% endif %}>
{% endif %}  
<div class="action-btn">
<p><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login"></p>
<p class="last">
  <a href="#" onclick="showRecoverPasswordForm();return false;" class="forgetpass">Forgot your password?</a>
  <span>or</span> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="register-form"> Register</a>
</p>
</div>
{% endform %}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    //    
var newletter = jQuery(".newsletterwrapper").html();
jQuery("body").after(newletter);  
var loggedin = jQuery(".userlogged").text();
var login = jQuery(".usernotlogged").text();        
   if(loggedin !=""){        
   closeEmailModalWindow();       
   }  
   if(login !=""){         
     openEmailModalWindow();     
   }
jQuery('#email-modal .btn.close').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    closeEmailModalWindow();
});
jQuery('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if( e.which == 27) {
        //closeEmailModalWindow();
        jQuery('body').unbind('keydown');
    }
});      
function closeEmailModalWindow (e) {


    jQuery('#email-modal .modal-window').fadeOut(600, function() {
        jQuery('#email-modal .modal-overlay').fadeOut(600, function() {
            jQuery('#email-modal').hide();
            //jQuery.cookie('emailSubcribeModal', 'closed', {expires:1, path:'/'});
        });
    })

}  
function openEmailModalWindow () {

 jQuery('#email-modal').fadeIn(600, function(e) {
       jQuery('#email-modal .modal-window').fadeIn(600);
       jQuery('.newsletterwrapper').remove();
       jQuery('#email-modal').css('display','block');             
       jQuery("body").attr('disabled',true);           
    });        
} 
   });
```

Comment: `e.stopPropogation()` ?

Comment: Doesn't work function openEmailModalWindow (e) { at the end I have added e.stopPropogation() }

Comment: Will you mind sharing a fiddle to work with ? I am unable to reproduce this...

Comment: Where is the popup ? There is no `script` in the provided fiddle...